# How do I decode nested JSON dictionaries in Swift, with variable keys and optionals?

Tags: json, swift, codable

Here's the JSON data I'm receiving:

```json
{
    "timestamp":"2023-03-09T07:41:30.899+01:00",
    "deviceName": "Mikrofon i MacBook Pro",
    "channelName": "Input 1-1",
    "metrics": [
        { "FS Peak": -46.79 },
        { "Peak C": 58.95},
        { "SPL Fast": 53.39, "violation": true},
        { "SPL A Fast": 34.31},
        { "SPL C Fast": 52.42},
        { "SPL Slow": 48.82 },
        { "SPL A Slow": 33.60 },
        { "SPL C Slow": 47.85},
        { "Leq 1": 53.69 },
        { "LAeq 1": 39.86 },
        { "LCeq 1": 52.71 },
        { "Leq 10": 51.55 },
        { "LAeq 13": 38.83 },
        { "LCeq 10": 50.57 },
        { "LAeq 42": 44.92 }
    ]
}
```

The issue I'm facing is regarding the data in `"metrics"`.
There's a `"violation": true` present in the data, which occurs when a given SPL (sound pressure level) is breached or violated. If no violation is occurring, the response would look like this:

```json
{
    "timestamp":"2023-03-09T07:41:30.899+01:00",
    "deviceName": "Mikrofon i MacBook Pro",
    "channelName": "Input 1-1",
    "metrics": [
        { "FS Peak": -46.79 },
        { "Peak C": 58.95},
        { "SPL Fast": 53.39 },
        { "SPL A Fast": 34.31},
        { "SPL C Fast": 52.42},
        { "SPL Slow": 48.82 },
        { "SPL A Slow": 33.60 },
        { "SPL C Slow": 47.85},
        { "Leq 1": 53.69 },
        { "LAeq 1": 39.86 },
        { "LCeq 1": 52.71 },
        { "Leq 10": 51.55 },
        { "LAeq 13": 38.83 },
        { "LCeq 10": 50.57 },
        { "LAeq 42": 44.92 }
    ]
}
```

The "gotcha" is found in the keys (FS Peak, Peak C, SPL Fast etc.). These keys can change, so i'm not able to reference them directly.

This would be easy to decode using `var metrics: [[String: Double]]` inside a `Codable` struct.

In order to decode the data if `"violation" true` is present, I've tried this approach:

```json
import Foundation

struct SplStream_Base : Codable {
    
    let sequenceNumber: Int?
    let timestamp : String?
    let deviceName : String?
    let channelName : String?
    var metrics: [[Metric]]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case sequenceNumber
        case timestamp
        case deviceName
        case channelName
        case metrics
    }
    
    struct Metric: Codable {
        let name: String
        let value: Double
        let violation: Bool?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case name = ""
            case value
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
                let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

                self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
                self.value = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .value)

                if let valueContainer = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: DynamicCodingKeys.self) {
                    if let _ = valueContainer.allKeys.first(where: { $0.stringValue == "violation" }) {
                        self.violation = true
                    } else {
                        self.violation = nil
                    }
                } else {
                    self.violation = nil
                }
            }
    }

    struct DynamicCodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            self.stringValue = stringValue
        }

        var intValue: Int? {
            return nil
        }

        init?(intValue: Int) {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        sequenceNumber = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .sequenceNumber)
        timestamp = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .timestamp)
        deviceName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .deviceName)
        channelName = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .channelName)

    }
    
}
```

Mind you, the above was provided by chatGPT, but I'm still getting `nil` in the response.

I'm open to all kinds of solutions. I've thought about adding `"violation": false` to all entries without `"violation": true` but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: `var metrics: [[Metric]]?` is wrong isn't it? I can't see an array of arrays in your json. Otherwise the `Metric` type looks ok but you should remove the `CodingKeys` enum and the `init(from:)` since they shouldn't be needed and also looks incorrect. Why are all properties in `SplStream_Base` optional, can everything really be null?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by reverting back to `JSONSerialization` instead.
That way I can manually decode `Any` and look for the expected value.

Here's what I did instead of using `Codable`:

```
do {
        if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: reply, options: []) as? [String: Any],
           let metrics = jsonObject["metrics"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            for metric in metrics {
                if let value = metric.values.first as? Double {
                    let key = metric.keys.first!
                    let hasViolation = metric["violation"] as? Bool == true
                    if hasViolation {
                       Print("Violation detected")
                    } else {
                       Print("No violation detected")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Failed to parse JSON data: \(error)")
    }
```

I don't know if this qualifies has a "hack job", but it works in my case.